# How to count duplicate ints

Tags: c

I want to count the amount of same used numbers in an int.

The if loop won't work why is that?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void){

    unsigned int digit;
    unsigned int n;
    int current_digit;

     scanf("%u", &digit);
     scanf("%u", &n);


     int i = 0;

    while(current_digit != n) {

        current_digit = n % 10;
        n /= 10;
             printf("%i", current_digit);
             if (current_digit == digit){
              i++;

         }

    }

     printf("%d", i);
}
```

I want the if loop to check how many time `digit` is used in `n`. But the if loop does not work properly.

Example: `digit` = 1`n` = 11111 Then the outcome should be 5 since 1 is used 5 times in `n` but the output is 4

Comment: A single `int` object can only hold one value at a time.For counting digits: it might be worth thinking twice. You enter a number by digits. Any reason you convert it first to an integer variable, then back to single digits?

Comment: To elaborate what @Olaf sir said, `if (digit == n)` is a flawed concept for what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: @EugeneSh. my bad - I thought he wanted the digit that occurred most often - I'll delete the comment.

Comment: @PaulR you read it good, that was my question yea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You "overwrite" the original `digit` (the one you are looking for) when you assign to it with `digit = n % 10`. If you consider the naming of the variables, you could have `searched_digit` and `current_digit`, then the check would be `if (current_digit == searched_digit)`.

(Admittedly such verbose variable names are not idiomatic C, but if you are just learning, do not add further complexity with cryptic or ambiguous naming.)

Furthermore, the `while` condition needs some work, `digit != n` may never be false... Try looping until there are no more digits.

Comment: Thanks! but how do i loop through the digits using a while loop?

Comment: @YoussefSakuragi You already do in the code posted in the question, just the counter and end condition are wrong…

Comment: @YoussefSakuragi Because the loop terminates too soon in that case, because the `while` condition is wrong, as stated in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You're writing code to undo what you asked `scanf()` to do for you, assemble textual digits into a number.  If instead you work with the unconverted text, it's somewhat simpler:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main () {

    char character, string[1024];

    (void) scanf("%c", &character);
    (void) scanf("%s", string);

    int count = 0;

    for (char *pointer = string; *pointer != '\0'; ++pointer) {

        if (*pointer == character) {
            count++;
        }
    }

    printf("%d\n", count);

    return 0;
}
```

**USAGE**

```
> ./a.out
1 11111
5
>
```

This might not solve your problem, but if so, then there's likely more to the problem than you've described (e.g. letters appear in the data so you need `scanf()` to help isolate numbers, etc.)